# Upload file using Java and Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a file using Selenium Webdriver and Java.. I have tried many of the suggestions listed such as

```
    WebElement fileInput = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='filepicker dropzone']"));
    fileInput.sendKeys("C:\\Users\\Documents\\Screening.pdf");
```

as well as the Robot class

```
    WebElement addFiles = driver.findElement(By.id("add-files"));
    addFiles.click();

    StringSelection filepath = new StringSelection("C:\\Users\\Documents\\Screening.pdf");
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(filepath, null);

    Robot robot = new Robot();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

But none of them seem to be working. The robot class opens the windows dialog, but won't interact with it at all.

Here is my what code looks like.

[Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOeST.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a mix of both, seems like your first statement is searching for the wrong element.
Try this:

```
WebElement addFiles = driver.findElement(By.id("add-files"));
addFiles.sendKeys("C:\\Users\\Documents\\Screening.pdf");
```

Comment: I tried using that element (By.id("add-files")) as well as (By.xpath("//div[@class='filepicker dropzone']")); and (By.xpath("//div[@class='dz-default dz-message']")); and (By.xpath("//div[@class='addFilesBtn']"));... But none of those locators will work.

Comment: @kc29 What Exception did you get when you tried all the above methods?

Comment: i don't receive an Exception.. It just moves on to the next line of code almost like it's ignoring this code.

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions you could try:

1) After the send keys you probably have to click some ok/submit button for that to work.

2) Using the robot: make sure the focus is on that dialog. Possibly you have to press some TAB or alt-TAB to ensure that it is focussed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.. I tried adding a submit, but it tries to submit my form instead of adding the attachment.I also tried the TAB as well as a switch to active element, neither one worked. And when it performs the CTRL+V, it pastes the file location within my test code.

Comment: Let's see if I understand: The ctrl-V does work, except that it pastes it in the wrong window/application? If that's true than my suggestion should be able to help you: before the ctrl-v have the robot press some tab or alt-tab to focus on the right app/window. (Or maybe cmd tab if you use mac?). Switching to the active element probably does not work since at that time you're not busy with the html or browser anymore.   For the submit: Is there no button on the screen somewhere next to the input field where you type the path+filename? If there is, find that button and click() it.

Comment: I tried putting in the Tab as well as ALT+Tab, but it's still behaving the same way... Here is my code and you can see where it's pasting it in, am I doing something wrong.         Robot robot = new Robot();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        C:\Users\Documents\Screening.pdf        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);

Comment: Also there isn't a submit button. It an Add files button that when clicked opens the windows dialog. When you choose a file and click Open on the windows dialog, it adds the file to what's called a filepicker dropzone, which is just an area.

Comment: Maybe you just have to put in some delays. When I used it I had to put them just about everywhere. robot.delay(time) will do that. Maybe it's just too fast. I believe the time is in milliseconds.

Comment: Putting in the delays worked.. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Good stuff! Good luck!